# No reminder notification

Tags: java, android, notifications, reminders

Android Target: O and above
I want to create a notification reminder for my application, which will remind the user of the expenses he had done today. I just made a test code to check if the application is giving notification or not but unfortunately its not.

NotifyService Class

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        Toast.makeText(NotifyService.this, "Startttttttttttttttttttttttttt Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent1, 0);
        Notification mNotify = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Log Steps!")
                .setContentText("Log your steps for today")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();
        mNM.notify(1, mNotify);
    }
}
```

NewAccountClass.java

```
public class NewAccount extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(this);
    private EditText user_name, pass_word, re_password;
    private TextView submit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_account2);

        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        int i = preferences.getInt("numberoflaunches", 1);
        if (i < 2){
            alarmMethod();
            i++;
            editor.putInt("numberoflaunches", i);
            editor.commit();
        }
        initialize();
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (pass_word.getText().toString().equals(re_password.getText().toString())) {
                    DataBaseHelper.writeNewAccountData(db.getWritableDatabase(), user_name.getText().toString(), pass_word.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Details Saved !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Doesn't Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //displayNotification(getApplicationContext());
                    //alarmMethod();
                    //new NotifyService().onCreate();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void alarmMethod(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this , NotifyService.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(NewAccount.this, "Start Alarm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    private void initialize() {
        user_name = findViewById(R.id.User_Name_New_Account);
        pass_word = findViewById(R.id.Password_New_Account);
        re_password = findViewById(R.id.Re_Password_New_Account);
        submit = findViewById(R.id.Submit_New_Account);
    }
}
```

When I set my time to 11:59 pm I m not getting any notification and also my Toast.makeText(NotifyService.this, "Startttttttttttttttttttttttttt Alarm"..) in notifyservice to create function isn't getting executed only. Any reasons why?